# Should I remove all the empty rows in a Dataframe before generating Word2Vec embeddings?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

The Pandas Dataframe column which I used to create the Word2Vec embeddings contains empty rows for some rows. It looks like this after tokenization--->`[]`. should I remove all such samples?

I have shared the code for tokenization and Word2Vec generation below:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
df['tweet_text'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
    
model = Word2Vec(df['tweet_text'], vector_size=300, window=10, hs=0, negative = 1)
```

If I don't remove such empty rows will it cause serious problems? If yes, what kinds of problems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That being said, you might want to use the pre-trained embedding layer made for twitter.  You can download it [here on huggingface](https://huggingface.co/Gensim/glove-twitter-25).

Comment: it's for a course project. At this point I'm not allowed to use that. If I don't remove such empty rows will it cause serious problems? If yes, what kinds of problems?

Comment: Well, if the row is empty, that means there were no valid words in the tweet. that means the word vector will also be empty.  therefore there will be no signal for the model to pick up on.  I dont see any upside to including empty rows.

Comment: Of course, no upside but is there any downside? That's what I want to know.